# @runTestsInSeparateProcesses annotation leads to error (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I am writing some tests that require me to use class aliased mocks. As a result, I need the app to revert back to the use of the class I am mocking once I am done with the mock (after running each of the test methods in which the mock is created). The mockery documentation mentions using this annotation to  run the tests in separate processes, which would accomplish what I need:

```
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
class FooTest
{
    //test methods here
}
```

However, `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` leads to this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader" not found in Standard input code:97`. I am using xdebug to generate the code coverage report. Not sure if this could be the cause of the problem.

I've checked that the Loader class is in `vendor` and I have added `use PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader;`, but I had no success.

I tried to edit the `phpunit.xml` file and change `processIsolation="false"` to `processIsolation="true"` (which would make all tests run slower, but would not require me to use the `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` annotation). This led to the following error: `The PHPUnit attribute 'processIsolation' with value 'true' is not supported yet.`

I tried adding `\Mockery::close()` at the end of each method in the test class, but this doesn't seem to revert back to the use of the original class instead of the mock class.

I've even tried to replace the original class with a new one that extends it and mock this new class so that the original one is left alone, but no success here either. It looked like this:

Helper class

```
class Bar
{
    public static function bar()
    {
       //bar method code;
    }
}
```

Method to be tested

```
public function foo()
{
   return Bar::bar();
}
```

Replacement helper class

```
class MockBar extends Bar
{
}
```

Tests:

```
class FooClassTest extends TestCase
{
   public function testFooMethod()
   {
      app()->instance(Bar::class, MockBar::class);
      $mock = Mockery::mock('alias:' . Bar::class);
      $mock->shouldReceive('bar')->once()->andReturn(true);

      //assertion

      app()->instance(MockBar::class, Bar::class);
    }
}
```

Any idea on what else I could try? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would assume that the static bar call is code that is not in your project?

Comment: The static bar call is code that is in my project. Bar is a helper class written by me that is used in the Foo controller class.